# Azure B2C Mobile App to 3rd Party App SSO

Tags: ios, mobile, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to SSO into a 3rd party mobile application from Azure AD B2C secured mobile application directly?(app to app)

I know we can do app to web to app using an interim auth web page as bridge but I was wondering if direct communication and SSO possible between apps? Let's say platform is iOS and app1 is secured with Azure AD B2C and app2 is with another IDP and we would like to jump from app1 into app2 without logging in again. If possible which protocol should we choose (oAuth, OpenID, SAML) and which libraries AppAuth, MSAL etc. should we consider using

Hope it is clear if not pls comment and I will extend the question

Comment: How will this work if app2 is using a different idp.  It would need to be using the same IDP; Azure B2C.

Comment: SSO between different IDPs (or more correctly between an IDP and an SP service provider ) is possible through protocols like SAML

Comment: You mean App1 and app2 are separate ios apps both work on different idps and you need to login into app2 account from app1 account in ios app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to open a second app and auto-sign on with some credentials, app2 can define a [custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app). Then app1 can use that scheme to open the app and provide the credentials/token.

More [About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899).

*caveat: I have not implemented this myself.*

Comment: Thank you, we will not know the user credentials but we can pass a token I guess. Your answer may be a workaround to what we are trying to do

Comment: yes, i meant credentials generically - some kind of token would be typical of a single-sign-on